# HTML Table Expands to End of Window in Email

Tags: html, html-table, width, html-email

I'm experiencing a bit of a frustrating problem with no real means to find solution...

I'm coding an HTML email and I have a particular table that is expanding all the way to the end of the browser. Everything I've tested this in (All browsers, Yahoo, Gmail, Outlook Mac 2011) did nothing of the sort. I received a screenshot from a recipient though that is very out of whack. I'm not sure how I can go about fixing this when everything I try it in looks fine...

Incorrect:

[image]

Correct:

[image]

As you can see in the screenshot, the center column is expanding as far as it can between the two columns beside it. In the correct screenshot you will see how it should actually appear.

If anyone can give me some kind of direction it would be greatly appreciated.

```html
<!--Container-->
<table cellpadding="0px" cellspacing="0px" width="600px" style="margin:0px auto;border:0px;border-spacing:0px;border-collapse:collapse;display:block;background-color:#1a223e;">
    <tr>
            <td style="vertical-align:top;">

<!--Left Column-->
<table width="227px" cellpadding="0px" cellspacing="0px" style="border:0px;border-spacing:0px;border-collapse:collapse;margin:0px auto;display:block;padding:0px;">
                            <tr>
                                    <td><a href="http://pesgm13.org/index1.asp?camp=TDGMEM2" style="border:0px;"><img src="left_image.jpg" width="227" height="932" style="display:block;border:0px;border-spacing:0px;border-collapse:collapse;vertical-align:top;background-color:#1a223e;" /></a></td>
                            </tr>
                    </table>
            </td>




    <td style="vertical-align:top;">  

            <!--Content-->
            <table width="340px" cellpadding="0px" cellspacing="0px" style="border:0px;border-spacing:0px;border-collapse:collapse;margin:0px auto;display:block;vertical-align:top;font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;font-size:14px;line-height:16px;font-weight:normal;color:#1a1a1a;background-color:#ffffff;">
                            <tr>
                                    <td style="vertical-align:top;display:block;">

                                    <img src="headline.jpg" width="271" height="85" style="display:block;margin:0px auto;border:0px;border-spacing:0px;border-collapse:collapse;background-color:#ffffff;margin-bottom:20px;padding-top:25px;" />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using the deprecated `width` and `height` attributes rather than CSS, you need to adhere to their semantics. The attributes take either a number value, implying pixels, or a percentage followed by a `%` as a value. So:

```
<table width="600">      <!-- correct -->
<table width="60%">      <!-- correct -->    
<table width="600px">    <!-- invalid attribute value! -->
```

Most HTML renderers aren't really pedantic about this, but it would appear your client found one that is. I'm pretty sure changing it to `width="600"` will fix your problem.

You can actually see on the *Incorrect* screenshot that this is the solution since it also ignores your `cellspacing` declarations, defaulting them back to the normal value of `1` because they have the `px` included. Note that even in CSS this is considered bad form - `0` has no dimension at all, and as such no unit to measure it in, so in CSS you should also always write `0` rather than `0px`, `0em` or `0%`.

Answer (score 0):

when you are coding email templates   always prefer to set  `<td width="600"> instead of <table width="600">`  , `set width for each  <td>` and  it will be ok  , let me know if it does not work